# PHP Simple HTML DOM parse ASPX page with internal script execution

Tags: javascript, php, html, simple-html-dom

I am trying to parse a price from a eCommerce website with Simple HTML Dom

My code works, but the website after page is loaded apply JavaScript code to the price, adding a promo-discount, but I am getting the price without it.

Is there a way to copy this JS and execute it after page loading? I've tried several solutions from here and none worked because it is internal JS.

Script example:

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="price-tmpl">***<script>
```

My code:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://www.example.aspx');
foreach($html->find('div.cost') as $e)
    echo $e->plaintext . '<br>';
?>
```